# How to remove EXIF (camera) data from image with carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exif, carrierwave

Does anybody know? 
With paperclip there was a special config command.

Removing camera data from image keeps 25-30 Kb per file. It's very sensitive if we make a lot of versions (thumb, small...). In small images the actual size of file without this information can be 5-6 times less.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Carrierwave is very flexible and it's possible to make own processors. With MiniMagick we can use a bunch of options of `mogrify` command-line utility, one of them is strip:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  version :small do
    process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100]
    process :strip
  end

  def strip
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.strip
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This should be `strip!`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone gets here and wonders why it doesn't work, it's because it should be `strip`, and not `strip!`. The method name is passed directly to ImageMagick, which does not understand `strip!`.